# Copiar a std::vector y destruir información original

Tags: c++, array, winapi

estoy intentando listar las conexiones a recursos compartidos. Me gustaría devolver un std::vector con esta información pero parece que cuando llamo a **NetApiBufferFree** esta información es eliminada y no entiendo el porque ya que en teoría copio el contenido, pero está claro que algo falla.

Aquí os dejo la función para ver si podéis ayudarme.

```
    const std::vector<USE_INFO_2>
    getConnections2shared() {
        typedef std::unique_ptr<USE_INFO_2, std::function<void(USE_INFO_2 *)> > USE_INFO_2_uptr_type;

        NET_API_STATUS result;
        DWORD EntriesRead, TotalEntries;
        USE_INFO_2_uptr_type uptrinfo(nullptr, [](USE_INFO_2 *f) {
            NetApiBufferFree(static_cast<LPVOID> (f));
        });
        USE_INFO_2 * puinfo;
        std::vector<USE_INFO_2> _ret;

        if ((result = NetUseEnum(
                NULL,
                2,
                reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE*> (&puinfo),
                MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH,
                &EntriesRead,
                &TotalEntries,
                NULL
                )) == NERR_Success) {
            uptrinfo.reset(puinfo);

            _ret.insert(_ret.end(), puinfo, &puinfo[TotalEntries]);

            /* Tampoco funciona así */    
            //_ret.resize(TotalEntries);
            //memcpy(&_ret[0], puinfo, TotalEntries * sizeof (USE_INFO_2));
        }

        /* Aquí la información es mostrada correcta*/
        for (USE_INFO_2 ui2 : _ret) {
            std::wcout << ":" << ui2.ui2_remote << std::endl;
        }
        return _ret;
    }
```

Y pretendo usarlo asi:

```
const std::vector<USE_INFO_2> connections = getConnections2shared();
```

Pero una vez llamado a **NetApiBufferFree** el contenido del vector se corrompe. Destacar que dentro de la función, muestra correctamente la información. He probado a quitar la llamada a **NetApiBufferFree** y entonces el fuera de la función comportamiento es el esperado.

Alguna idea?

Gracias!

Comment: si es const, ¿cómo esperas poder copiarlo?
Relacionado: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716330/purpose-of-returning-by-const-value

Comment: Es declarado y definido a la vez, por lo que no debería haber problema (al igual que pasa con const int i=1;), de todas formas he probado sin const y sigue fallando.

Comment: ¿Por qué haces `_ret.insert(_ret.end(), puinfo, &puinfo[TotalEntries]);` en lugar de `_ret.push_back(*uptrinfo)`?

Comment: Así estaba originalmente, pero también fallaba. En ambos casos en el ámbito de la función todo funciona perfectamente, el problema viene cuando una vez liberada la memoria mediante NetApiBufferFree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es muy normal que te falle. Repasemos `USE_INFO_2`:

```
typedef struct _USE_INFO_2 {
  USE_INFO_1 ui2_useinfo;
  wchar_t* ui2_username;
  wchar_t* ui2_domainname;
 } USE_INFO_2,
```

> ui2_useinfo: A pointer to the USE_INFO_1 (section 2.2.5.22) structure entries returned by the method.
>   
>   ui2_username: A pointer to a string that contains the name of the user who initiated the connection.
>   
>   ui2_domainname: A pointer to a string that contains the domain name of the remote resource.

Y ahora, USE_INFO_1:

```
typedef struct _USE_INFO_1 {
  wchar_t* ui1_local;
  wchar_t* ui1_remote;
  wchar_t* ui1_password;
  long ui1_status;
  unsigned long ui1_asg_type;
  unsigned long ui1_refcount;
  unsigned long ui1_usecount;
 } USE_INFO_1,
```

Como se ve, *3/4* de los mismo: mas punteros.

Por si mismas, esas estructuras **solo contiene punteros**, los cuales dejan de ser válidos en cuanto llamas a `NetApiBufferFree( )`.

Tienes varias opciones. Personalmente, usaria mi propia clase `MyUseInfo2` con un constructor que se encargara de copiar los datos importantes:

> ejemplo:

```
struct MyUseInfo {
  std::wstring local;
  std::wstring remote;
  std::wstring password;
  long status;
  ...
  std::wstring user;
  std::wstring domain;

  MyUseInfo( USE_INFO_2 * ) { ... }
};
```

Y luego lo podrías usar facilmente en tu código, cambiando tu `std::vector<USE_INFO_2>` por `std::vector< MyUseInfo >`.

Comment: Muchas gracias y tienes toda la razón, ya me había obcecado y no veía mas allá de mis narices.

Comment: @p4klt0 Es normal, nos pasa a todos. La técnica del *patito-de-goma*, ir a contarles las penas a otros, es **muy** util :-)